# Why do I have a short between 3.3V and GND in my FPGA circuit?

Tags: power, circuit-design, fpga, short-circuit

I've trying to design a circuit that converts digital video to an HDMI compliant format, based on [this schematic](https://www.retro-system.com/video%20-%20Schematic_v3.pdf).

This is the design I have come up with in order to make use of newer, more available components and in order to design my own board layout, but for some reason whenever I solder the FPGA onto the board, I get shorts between 3.3 V and GND, and I can't figure out why. It might be something obvious, but I've spent so long staring at it that I'm going crazy.

[image]

I am using a Xilinx XC3S200A rather than an XC3S50A, but the only differences mentioned on the datasheet are some swapped differential I/O pairs: P29 and P30, which are both tied to 3.3 V anyway, P33 and P34, which are floating, and P51 and P52, of which I'm using P51 for MISO (shown below). I've checked the soldering under a microscope a number of times and can't see any evidence of physical shorts between any of the pins. I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious, but as I said I've stared at it for ages without anything jumping out, so if anyone else could cast their eyes over it that'd be great.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the resistance between 3.3V and GND of an *unsoldered* FPGA chip by probing its pins? Just so that you can see if the chips themselves are okay. Also, large FPGA and ASIC can have an internal impedance so low that it's indistinguishable from a short circuit - it's not the case here, but it would be useful to keep that in mind for future projects.

Comment: I'll check this - the couple of FPGAs I have were Aliexpress specials I bought some time ago, so it's not out of the question, although they had a number of positive reviews

Comment: If the FPGAs are from Aliexpress, it wouldn't suprise me if they are fakes or factory rejects. Reviews can be faked as easily as the chips.